# How to store fill and font color of every cell in a range in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, colors, fill

When I refresh the data from my database, any fill/font color gets moved when new rows are added. I want to add to my refresh macro

1. Store current fill/font color information
2. Clear it all
3. Refresh data
4. reapply colors to proper cells

This is my current code that does the same thing with my manual notes columns

```
    plannerData = plannerSheet.Range("A3:BO" & CStr(lastRowPlanner))
    historyData = historySheet.Range("A2:BO" & CStr(lastRowHistory))
    lastRowPlannerData = UBound(plannerData, 1)
    lastRowHistoryData = UBound(historyData, 1)


    For plannerRow = 1 To lastRowPlannerData
        plannerValue = plannerData(plannerRow, 4) 'get the work order number
        
        For historyRow = 1 To lastRowHistoryData
            historyValue = historyData(historyRow, 4) 'check the work order number in this row
            
            If plannerValue = historyValue Then 
                For i = LBound(columnsToCopy) To UBound(columnsToCopy)
                    plannerData(plannerRow, columnsToCopy(i)) = historyData(historyRow, columnsToCopy(i))
                Next i
                
                Exit For 'no need to keep searching the history, move on to the next planner row
                
            End If
            
        Next historyRow
    
    Next plannerRow
    
    'so now we have restored planner data in memory
    'we can reset the planner spreadsheet accordingly
    plannerSheet.Range("A3:BO" & CStr(lastRowPlanner)).Value = plannerData
```

I'm not sure if I can modify this code to work with the colors since currently it's just dealing with text

Comment: Just curious, how did you fill/font color to proper cells before those steps you mentioned ? If you did it manually, then I think you can ommit #1 and in #4 you define the condition which fall into the category of "proper cell". Example : you manually fill yellow color to all cells which value are "test". The cells are A2 and B5. So even though the code for #1 store the information that there are yellow fill in A2 and B5, but then in #4 the code will never now what is the "proper cells" to reapply the yellow. So in #4 you need to tell "if the cell value is test - then fill yellow". Pease CMIIW

Comment: how/when is `historySheet` populated?  Just before the refresh?   Once you've matched the rows, you will need to copy the fill and font colors from the history sheet back to the planner sheet.  It might be kind of slow depending on how much data you have, but you can probably copy/pastespecial>formats for the whole row instead of going cell-by-cell

Comment: ...or change how you run the refresh, and update the table instead of replacing if completely (which I'm guessing is how you're doing it currently?)

Comment: Answering the questions asked: Font/fill color will be changed by the user manually using the ribbon. The history sheet is populated by copying the planner sheet to the bottom of the history sheet, sorting the history by date added, and then removing duplicates based on the work order number (unique ID). Then, the planner sheet table is refreshed which pulls new data from our SQL db

Comment: The logic for copying cell color/fill would be similar - match rows on work order number, then copy any fill/font color from which ever columns are appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim i As Long    
Dim fillColor() As Variant
Dim fillColorDimension As Long

fillColorDimension = 0
For Each cell In plannerSheet.Range("A3:BT" & lastRowPlanner)
    If cell.Interior.Color <> 16777215 Then
     fillColorDimension = fillColorDimension + 1
    End If
Next cell

If fillColorDimension <> 0 Then
    i = 1
    ReDim fillColor(1 To fillColorDimension, 1 To 3)
    For Each cell In plannerSheet.Range("A3:BT" & lastRowPlanner)
        If cell.Interior.Color <> 16777215 Then
            cellRow = cell.Row
            fillColor(i, 1) = plannerSheet.Range("D" & cellRow).Value
            fillColor(i, 2) = cell.Column
            fillColor(i, 3) = cell.Interior.Color
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End If

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

For colorRow = 1 To fillColorDimension
    For Each cell In plannerSheet.Range("D3:D" & lastRowPlanner)
        If cell = fillColor(colorRow, 1) Then
            plannerSheet.Cells(cell.Row, fillColor(colorRow, 2)).Interior.Color = fillColor(colorRow, 3)
        End If
    Next cell
Next colorRow
```

My workbook is 72 columns long and I tested it with ~700 rows. If all 50,400 cells have a fill color, this takes about 25 seconds. Considering my users will likely not be highlighting more than 10% of those cells, it should be much faster than that.

I use column D because that is where the work order number is stored. This acts as a primary key for the data. If a data set does not have a unique key like this, it would need an artificial one. This, i believe, is usually done with an index(?)

Also, this does not copy the fill colors to the history sheet. The history sheets main point was to track WOs that fell off after refresh because of closure, and tracking their notes on those was important. Colors, not so much. But the same process could be applied to copy colors from the planner sheet to the history sheet